# Accessing forms variables from Task

Tags: vb.net

Is there anything wrong when task is accessing form's variables or could it be some problems related to it?

Below you can see an example. `_counter` is form's variable as well as `_subkategorie.Id and sentence.Id`. When pic shows - this is the other form which showing up to user when long task is running. This additional form will be closed when task finalize the job, so ShowDialog will unlock automatically main form. This task is accessing form's variables as can be seen.

```
_counter = 0 'this is form's variable
  For _counter = 0 To LbSubkategories.Items.Count - 1
       If LbSubkategories.SelectedItems.Contains(LbSubkategories.Items(_counter)) Then     
            _subKategorieId = New Subkategorie().GetIdByName(LbSubkategories.GetItemText(LbSubkategories.Items(_counter)))

            pic = New FrmCircularProgress(eCircularProgressType.Donut)
            pic.ShowDialog()
            'Task.WaitAll(tsk_doesConnectionExist)  'not need as ShowDialog not return after pic is closed so further lines below will be not executed before it closed

    End If
Next
```

This is what will be fired when _pic form will show up. See i use there _counter variable and two other variables mentioned before.

```
Public Sub DoTheJobWhenPicShown() Handles pic.Shown
    tskDoesConnectionExist = Task.Run(Of Boolean)(Function()
    Dim resu = False

    Try
        resu = New AmbessSentenceSubKategorie(_subKategorieId, _sentence.Id).CheckIfConnectionAlreadyExist()
       If resu = True Then
               LbSubkategories.Invoke(Sub()
                 LbSubkategories.SetSelected(_counter, False)
               End Sub)
        pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.LabelX1.Text = "Ende"))

            End If
            Catch ex As SqlException
            pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() MessageBoxEx.Show(pic, ex.ToString(), Msg.T(eMsgCaption.Err), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)))
            Catch ex As Exception
            pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() MessageBoxEx.Show(pic, ex.ToString(), Msg.T(eMsgCaption.Err), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)))
            Finally
             '--Close form once done (on GUI thread)
            pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.StopCircular()))
        pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.Close()))
        End Try

Return resu
End Function)
End Sub
```

Comment: If there's a risk of multiple threads hitting the variable at once, then you need to worry about locking them to prevent collisions.

Comment: What about this concrete example?

Comment: [**`SyncLock` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement)